# 74LS04 (5 V) outputs 1.2 V to input pins

Tags: digital-logic, inverter

I have tree 74LS04 inverters and I cannot make them work. 
When I connect device to power and ground and measure input voltage pin using multimeter, it read 1.2 V, which I expected to be 0.
The device sees it as 5V and inverts so my output is 0 instead of 1. 
I tried all input pins, and they are all at 1.2 V; I've tried using two other devices from the same bulk and they all show the same behavior.

Is it a user or hardware error?

Comment: Are you actually *applying* any voltage to the input from other sources?

Comment: Yes, I used a power supply at school and arduino pin at home. I measured voltage with multimeter both times.

Comment: user error. inputs are meant to be driven by something. standard practice is to drive with an output, to pull up, to ground, etc. Any voltage you might read on an input that is in an otherwise unconnected state is just irrelevant.

Comment: A schematic would make your situation easier to understand.

Comment: Both Peter's an Jim's solutions helped me. Thank you. I've realized though that I don't ever need to leave input open so it should all be alright now.

Answer (score 2):

The inputs to 74LS logic chips are emitters of NPN transistors.  If left open-circuit, they will usually be seen as high.  If you wish to input a low, you must connect the input pin to ground.

Traditionally, switch inputs to 74LS logic have used a 5K (or so) resistor from the input to Vcc, and a switch between the input pin and ground.  The 5K pull-up resistor ensures that the input will be high, unless the switch is closed.

Since the TTL inputs source current, a fairly low resistance to ground is required to input a low, so it is best to use a pull-up resistor and a switch to ground.

With CMOS parts (74HCnn or CD4nnn) the inputs are very high impedance and must not be left open-circuit.  Because CMOS inputs neither source nor sink current, switch inputs may be connected as above, or with a switch to Vcc and resistor to ground.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. I'm not sure how to make it work if the value of input will change every second.

Comment: @user1078719 - whatever is driving the input of the gate must pull the input very close to ground to be recognized as a low input - both TTL and CMOS logic, as well as most microcontroller outputs should do this with no problem.

Comment: Ok, I think, I understand what to do. It sound more complicated than I expected though

Answer (score 0):

The standard TTL logic gate use the multiple emitter transistor.
[image]

With nothing connected to an input they will assume the input is high. If you measure the input with a voltmeter they will show a voltage of about 1 - 2V because there is a conductive path from the 5V supply, through the 4K resistor and the base-emitter junction of Q1.

When you apply a '0' you need to conduct a small input current to ground. (typically a mA or so). The output stage of the gate is capable of driving (sinking enough current) about 10 such inputs.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I must use a bit counter to implement this circuit and when it will output 0, I need to get 1 coming out of inverter and when bit counter outputs 0, (assuming voltage on a inverter pin will still be 1.2V) I will still get 0 out of inverter.

Comment: The class I'm taking has no prerequisites in device physics and there is no mentioning of that's the output of input pin is nonzero. I'm still under impression that I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @user1078719 There's no problem when you connect the output of one device (such as a counter) to the input of the gate - it automatically takes it to high or low and the logic works as it should. As a matter of good design all unused logic inputs should be tied either high or low as appropriate.